# Observing how an MSI installer is installing an application

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-installer

I am trying to find out how a driver is being installed on the system from a MSI setup package. I am currently using a program called InstEd to try and get an idea of what its doing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFWnQ.jpg

I am interested in "MsiProcessDrivers" and "MsiInstallDrivers".

Can anyone reccomend how I can see how the drivers are being installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MS Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021) has some tools for monitoring registry and disk operations. Just run them prior to running the installation, and note the actions that are performed by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Sysinternal's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) will show file system and registry changes being made: filter by `msiexec` processes.

Warning: for a non-trivial install this is likely to be a lot of operation.

Answer (score 0):

The two custom actions you reference (MsiProcessDrivers, and MsiInstallDrivers) are part of the [DIFx Driver Installation Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463103) as used with [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537784%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).